# Simple Custom ListView Application. Crashes every time

Tags: android

I am a newbie in Android, so I am really sorry if the error that you will encounter is a blunder. I tried making a Custom ListView (An ImageView and a TextView in each row) by using custom_row.xml as the layout file and CustomAdapter.java as the customized adapter.

I do not understand why this application crashes every time I run the same. The exception (As shown in Android Monitor) is caused at this very line in the CustomAdapter.java file.

```
View customView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
```

I am attaching all of the Java and Layout codes for the reference. Thanks.

CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.abhinavankur.listexample;


import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] teams) {
    super(context,R.layout.custom_row,teams);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

    String singleTeam = getItem(position);
    TextView myText = (TextView)  customView.findViewById(R.id.myText);
    ImageView myImage= (ImageView) customView.findViewById(R.id.myImage);

    myText.setText(singleTeam);
    myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.mine);
    return customView;
}
}
```

custom_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/myImage"
    android:src="@drawable/mine"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:id="@+id/myText"
    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.abhinavankur.listexample.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myListView">
</ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.abhinavankur.listexample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


String teams[] = {"Real Madrid","Manchester United","Barcelona","Chelsea","Bayern Munich","PSG","Borussia Dortmund","Liverpool","Arsenal","Valencia","Villareal","Leicester City","AS Roma"};

    ListAdapter myAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, teams);
    ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    myList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    Toast.makeText(this,"List Shown",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    myList.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    String team = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,team,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

}

Comment: "The exception (As shown in Android Monitor)" So what is it?

Comment: Add the complete logcat of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `CustomAdapter` as below. You were inflating the layout in a wrong way.

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    Context context;

    CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] teams) {
        super(context,R.layout.custom_row,teams);
        this.context = context
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, null);
        }

        ....
        ....

}
```

Comment: I changed it, the way you said, but the problem persists. Also I don't understand what was wrong in my version of inflating the layout.

The error in logcat is as follows:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.abhinavankur.listexample, PID: 7943
                                                                            java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=12504KB, Allocated=3490KB)